# Using keyword "value" in set accessor C#

Tags: c#, arrays, class, object, set

I'm trying to use the keyword `value` in the set accessor and as long as the user entered value is greater than 0, I want to set it to the variable `Quantity`.

I can not seem to find what it is I am doing wrong. I keep getting a traceback error to for this `Quantity = value;`. Hoping someone can see what I don't. Thanks.

```
using System;

namespace Invoice
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("How many parts would you like to " +
                "enter into the system: ");
            int newParts = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Invoice[] invoice = new Invoice[newParts];

            for (int i = 0; i < newParts; i++)
            {
                invoice[i] = new Invoice();

                Console.WriteLine("Enter the part number: ");
                invoice[i].PartNumber = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Enter description of item: ");
                invoice[i].PartDescription = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Enter the quantity: ");
                invoice[i].Quantity = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("Enter in the price of the item: ");
                invoice[i].PricePerItem = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < newParts; i++)
            {
                invoice[i].DisplayOrder();

            }
        }
    }
}


using System;
namespace Invoice
{
    public class Invoice
    {
        public string PartNumber { get; set; }
        public string PartDescription { get; set; }

        public int Quantity
        {
            get { return Quantity; }

            set
            {
                if (value >= 0)
                {
                    Quantity = value;
                }

                if (value <= 0)
                {
                    Quantity = Quantity;
                }
            }
        }

        public decimal PricePerItem
        {
            get
            {
                return PricePerItem;
            }

            set
            {
                if(value >= 0.0m)
                {
                    PricePerItem = value;
                }

                if (value <= 0.0m)
                {
                    PricePerItem = PricePerItem;
                }
            }
        }

        public Invoice(String PartNumber, String PartDescription, int Quantity, decimal PricePerItem)
        {
            this.PartNumber = PartNumber;
            this.PartDescription = PartDescription;
            this.Quantity = Quantity;
            this.PricePerItem = PricePerItem;
        }

        public Invoice()
        {
        }

        public decimal GetInvoiceAmount(int numberOfItems, decimal priceOfItem)
        {
            return numberOfItems * priceOfItem;
        }

        public void DisplayOrder()
        {
            decimal total = GetInvoiceAmount(Quantity, PricePerItem);

            // Display Receipt
            Console.Write("\nOrder Receipt: ");

            Console.WriteLine($"\nPart Number: {PartNumber}");

            Console.WriteLine($"Unit Price: {PricePerItem:C}");

            Console.WriteLine($"Quantity: {Quantity}");

            Console.WriteLine($"Part Description: {PartDescription}");

            Console.WriteLine($"Total price: {total:C}");
        }

 
    }
}
```

Comment: What is a "traceback error"?  Do you mean stackoverflow exception?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `if (value >= 0)` and `if (value <= 0)` when the `value` is zero then both branches will be executed.

Comment: Also there is an infinite loop, since you don't have a backing field for `Quantity`. So inside your setter you are calling the same setter again and again and ... again.

Comment: Part of the reason it's hard to tell what you're asking about is that there's rather a lot of code here - 126 lines where I suspect you could demonstrate *just the point you're asking about* in roughly 20 lines. Please edit your question to clarify it and provide a *minimal* but complete example.

Comment: @PeterCsala: Well, infinite *recursion* which will cause a stack overflow.

Answer (score 4):

This makes no sense:

```cs
if (value >= 0)
{
    Quantity = value;
}

if (value <= 0)
{
    Quantity = Quantity;
}
```

Why would you set a property to itself? That can't achieve anything useful. You say that you want to set the property if and only if the assigned value is greater than zero, so why would you be checking `value` for anything but being greater than zero?

```cs
if (value > 0)
{
    Quantity = value;
}
```

That's it, that's all.

That said, you also ought to be throwing an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` if the value is not valid, rather than just silently not setting the property. The logical way to do that would be like so:

```cs
if (value <= 0)
{
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(...);
}

Quantity = value;
```

Now the property value will only be set if an exception is not thrown.

I also just realised that you have no backing field for this property, so that's wrong. The whole thing should look like this:

```cs
private int quantity;

public int Quantity
{
    get { return quantity; }

    set
    {
        if (value <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(...);
        }

        quantity = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is because in your set {} you are invoking the same setter recursively.

```
        private int quantity; 
        public int Quantity
        {
            get { return  this.quantity; }

            set
            {
                if (value >= 0)
                {
                     this.quantity= value;
                }
            }
        }

        private decimal pricePerItem;
        public decimal PricePerItem
        {
            get
            {
                return  this.pricePerItem;
            }

            set
            {
                if(value >= 0.0m)
                {
                     this.pricePerItem= value;
                }
            }
        }
```